# React input is wether readonly or doesnt show my defaultValue

Tags: reactjs

When I do the following, the input field will show my value BUT will be readonly:

```
<input id="topbar-zoominput" value={zoomPercent} onChange={(e) => console.debug('TopBar -> handleManualZoom', e)} />
```

And when I do it like the following, it will NOT be readonly but it will not show my defaultValue:

```
<input id="topbar-zoominput" defaultValue={zoomPercent} onChange={(e) => console.debug('TopBar -> handleManualZoom', e)} />
```

I know about the readonly, value, defaultValue, onChange and because of that i thought it should work.

My target is to have it writeable and that it shows my default value.

Answer (score 0):

First case with `value={zoomPercent}` (the recommanded one for having [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)):

- You have to put `zoomPercent` in your component state:  `value={this.state.zoomPercent}`
- Then the prop `onChange` should modify this state to have the input value modified: `onChange={(e) => this.setState({zoomPercent:e.target.value});`

Second case with `defaultValue={zoomPercent}`:

- Either zoomPercent was `undefined` at [first rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value) and that's why the default value is never set.
- Or maybe (it is to try), you should had `type="text"` ot `<input>` tag.